# What kind of video connector is this, if not VGA?

Tags: video, cable, vga

Can anyone identify this connector type? It is nothing I have seen before, and we have one that is converting from this connector to VGA. It needs to be replaced but with no idea what it is exactly.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [a DMS-59 connector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMS-59).  They're commonly used as splitters - there are a lot of cards with single DMS-59 outputs that'll output two separate signals (due to pin density).

Comment: Thank you, it seems no one here could pick that one out

Comment: That's unsurprising - you don't see it very much except on low profile cards or quad output cards.  (It's still more common than VHDCI but that isn't saying much.)

Answer (score 4):

The specific name is the [DMS-59](http://pinoutsguide.com/Video/dms_59_pinout.shtml).  I've only seen these on smaller towers.  Here is a pic of the female connection from the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMS-59) article:

[image: DMS-59 video cable]