# What is this monitor connection?

Tags: display, connection

We have an older Dell Dimension GX280, and it has a VGA output, as well as an additional video out (dedicated PCI graphics card), that looks like this:

[image]

When we boot the PC, it asks to have the monitor connected to the video out on the graphics card.  I know we can disconnect the graphics card and use the VGA, but we'd like to use this port (it's used for dual monitors, I suspect).

**What is this monitor connection called?**

Comment: It's called broken. :) Looks like someone tried to plug a DVI into a DMS59.

Comment: What's with the downvote? I put in some time researching this before asking a question - I had a hunch it was DVI, but couldn't find anything about this...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a [DMS-59 connector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMS-59).  They're generally used with a splitter to dual DVI - the reason for the high pin density is to support two separate output channels.

This particular one looks like it's been roughly treated (you can see some damage to the plastic housing between pins in a couple of places).  I point this out specifically because DMS-59 connectors are incredibly picky because of the high pin density and small pin size - I see bent or broken pins on these not infrequently, so it's something to be aware of.

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/237166/what-kind-of-video-connector-is-this-if-not-vga

Comment: Yeah, I had one like that somewhere I worked a while ago I think. It needed a special plug which split out into two DVI ports (I think).

Comment: I have approximately 1 million splitter cables for this connector in my office. A dual DVI and a dual VGA version come with every Dell OptiPlex system we order.

Comment: @WilliamJackson :P we could use one (also in an office with lots of Optiplex's)